# Passing "Complex" Strings to prepared statement with bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In the program I'm writing the user defines the order that the requested data is displayed. As of right now the query looks like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare(SELECT `fieldsHere` FROM `scansbasic` WHERE `system` = ? OR `iffStatus` = ? OR 1 = ? ORDER BY ?);
```

my bind_param() statement:

```
$stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $bind_system, $bind_iffStatus, $bind_selector, $orderBy);
```

Where $orderBy looks like this in one example:

```
`x` DESC, `y` DESC, `system`, FIELD(`iffStatus`, 'Enemy', 'Neutral', 'Friend'), `typeName`, `entityID`, `ownerName`, `name`
```

There are no errors generated but the order never changes. Is there something I'm needing to do to make it recognize the order passed to the statement?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between **SQL string literal** (which only can be called "a string") and arbitrary SQL query part which, although being indeed a string from PHP point of view, but on SQL part it is not a string by no means but rather part of the program.

Comment: You better rephrase your question, taking out useless code and explaining what certainly user can choose instead.

Comment: Ah makes sense . . . I'm still getting used to prepared statements in general but no need to get offensive about it, you answered my question with the first comment.

Comment: No need to look for offense where it isn't. With first comment I have answered only why your code won't work. While second is aimed to finding a proper solution in replace.